# Linkedin OAuth2 - how to make implicit request?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement `LinkedIn OAuth2 via Javascript`. However, unlike other networks who have oauth2.0, I cant find a way to get `implicit grant` here.

Is there a way to do it like done with `Yahoo` and `Outlook.com`? Or I must always first get Code, then token as mentioned here (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to Andrew Dodson (author of the hello.js library for OAuth communication - hence IMO an authority on the subject)

> LinkedIn only support the explicit flow at present.

(as of 2014).

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530702/hello-js-and-linkedin) and [here](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy)