# Completing the OAuth2 flow for Sign In with LinkedIn entirely from the client side

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

With LinkedIn's planned deprecation of their JS SDK, is there any way to complete the OAuth2 flow and obtain an access token from the client-side, without using a server-side proxy to exchange the auth code for the token?

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431287/linkedin-oauth2-how-to-make-implicit-request), LinkedIn does not allow for an implicit grant flow. It's from 2015, but appears to still be relevant.

Is there any alternative way I can obtain an access token for a user who authenticated with LinkedIn, without hitting a self-hosted proxy? My application only needs basic profile data for the user.

**Edit**

To provide more context, the error I receive when making the second request to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. The same request made from postman works fine and returns the access token.  I understand this CORS issue comes down to browser policy. Right now I'm testing from localhost over https.  Once the front end code is deployed to a proper domain, will the error persist? Is there any alternative way to get around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, wondering about the same issue, have you made any luck on this?

Comment: Hey @flylib - We ended up just doing a code grant flow with a proxy and abandoning the implicit flow. So no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: This should theoretically work for your use case https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce